# iterm2 became slow and drags after installing powerline9k zsh theme

Tags: git, iterm2

I installed the powerline9k theme for oh-my-zsh from https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k.

On restarting my iterm2, I found out that it was very slow and drags especially when trying to access a git repo.

There's no much report on this online, so I find it very strange that I am experiencing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew install git` did the trick.
Doing this overrides the default git that was shipped with my OSX.

Comment: I do not use oh-my-zsh, but I was experiencing trouble with the iterm2 zsh integrations slowing down my prompt. Installing the Homebrew's git fixed the issue.